# ! Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: guava

I wrote an api to fetch gcs bucket size using stackdriver metrics. However, it is throwing error ! Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V

I tried changing guava versions but that did not work.